# Canonicalize string using CultureInfo and CompareOptions

Tags: .net, globalization

Currently I have code, which based on a `CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ja-JP")` does a search using

```
bool found = cultureInfo.CompareInfo.IndexOf(x, y,
    CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | 
    CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType | 
    CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth
) >= 0;
```

As doing a `x.IndexOf(y)` is way faster, and my `x`es are plenty and rarely change, I'd like to canonicalize the `x`es once, and when performing the search do a simple

```
canonicalizedX.indexOf(canonicalize(y));
```

My question: Is there anything in the .net libraries which I could use do implement the `canonicalize()` function, using my `CultureInfo` and `CompareOptions`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `LCMapStringEx` and it works fine for me. It is not based upon (an arbitrary set of) `CompareOptions`, but the [CompareInfo.GetSortKey docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7ecsckw.aspx) lead me to `LCMapString`, so the effect of my `indexOf` of canonicalized strings should be yield the same result as `CultureInfo.CompareInfo.IndexOf`, using the hardcoded `CompareOptions`, here called `dwMapFlags`:

```
public static string Canonicalize(string src)
{
    string localeName = "ja-JP";
    string nResult = src;

    int nLen, nSize;

    uint dwMapFlags = LCMAP_LOWERCASE | LCMAP_HIRAGANA | LCMAP_FULLWIDTH;
    IntPtr ptr, pZero = IntPtr.Zero;

    nLen = src.Length;
    nSize = LCMapStringEx(localeName, dwMapFlags, src, nLen, IntPtr.Zero, 0, pZero, pZero, pZero);
    if (nSize > 0)
    {
        nSize = nSize * sizeof(char);
        ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(nSize);
        try
        {
            nSize = LCMapStringEx(localeName, dwMapFlags, src, nLen, ptr, nSize, pZero, pZero, pZero);
            if (nSize > 0) nResult = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptr, nSize);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
    }

    return nResult;
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
static extern int LCMapStringEx(
     string lpLocaleName,
     uint dwMapFlags,
     string lpSrcStr,
     int cchSrc,
     [Out]
     IntPtr lpDestStr,
     int cchDest,
     IntPtr lpVersionInformation,
     IntPtr lpReserved,
     IntPtr sortHandle);

private const uint LCMAP_LOWERCASE = 0x100;
private const uint LCMAP_UPPERCASE = 0x200;
private const uint LCMAP_SORTKEY = 0x400;
private const uint LCMAP_BYTEREV = 0x800;
private const uint LCMAP_HIRAGANA = 0x100000;
private const uint LCMAP_KATAKANA = 0x200000;
private const uint LCMAP_HALFWIDTH = 0x400000;
private const uint LCMAP_FULLWIDTH = 0x800000;
```

I also tried [Microsoft.VisualBasic.StrConv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd7w43ec.aspx), which works, but is twice as slow as pinvoking `LCMapStringEx`.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking: "Does .NET give me a way to map katakana to hirigana and full width to half width so I can perform a fast comparison?"  To which the answer is a resounding No.  You'd have to implement that yourself.

Which is quite difficult.  String comparison in .NET is driven by rather extensive character comparison tables.  They are however optimized for comparison, not for character substitution.  You can get some insight in the way the CLR does this by looking at the source code.  Download the SSCLI20 distribution and take a look at the clr\src\classlibnative\nls\sortingtable.cpp source code file.  The NativeCompareInfo::LongCompareStringW() function does the comparison, you'll see it use the COMPARE_OPTIONS_IGNOREKANATYPE and COMPARE_OPTIONS_IGNOREWIDTH flags.  Note how it uses special rules for Kana, taking the "slow path".  This function is *massive*, the odds that you can reverse-engineer a substitution algorithm from this are sufficiently low to zero to give this up quickly.  Japanese orthography is *complicated*.

If the strings you compare are stable then consider storing the comparison result and re-use that.

Comment: Japanese orthography is probably the most complicated around, but canonicalization, in this case conversion of a Utf-16 string to lowercase, hiragana, fullwidth characters is pretty straightforward, if you know the language and Unicode a little bit. It is basically like `toLowerCase`, except instead of a single "code point range + offset" combo, you have one for each hiragana, katakana, half-width katakana, full-width latin. I'd like to reuse any of the existing wheel though. The [CompareInfo.GetSortKey docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7ecsckw.aspx) btw lead me to `LCMapString`

Comment: Re: "re-use comparison result". My "haystack" is quite stable, but the "needle" is not. So what I'm actually doing when searching is a simple lookup in a **[suffix array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)** that I create once for every string in the haystack. Turns out to be way faster than `String.IndexOf`, not surprising for a tree structured index.